# Get ID allocation through Cypher query (or bolt protocol)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the Neo4j browser, I can do `:play sysinfo` or

```
:GET /db/manage/server/jmx/domain/org.neo4j/instance%3Dkernel%230%2Cname%3DPrimitive%20count
```

to get the ID allocation for nodes and relationships. Is there a way to get the same information through a Cypher query so that I can request it via the bolt protocol? I know I can write a query that searches all the nodes/relationships and returns the largest ID, but that's slow on a large db so I'd prefer something that can directly access the stored property.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/procedures/#built-in-procedures), particularly `dbms.queryJmx()`. For this particular query,

```
CALL dbms.queryJmx('org.neo4j:instance=kernel#0,name=Primitive count')
```

If you want to explore what else you can grab, just pass in `'org.neo4j:*'` as the query string instead. The exact structure of the results can get pretty... interesting depending on your choice of driver, so it may take some parsing work.

Comment: Btw, you really should not rely on that data to make predictions about what ID's will be next or anything else, because neo4j does reserve the right to recycle or even change the internal ID's. So be very careful what you design around this information.

Comment: Thank you! Don't worry - it's not about making predictions. It's because I'm writing code to delete all nodes based on their label, and I know it's faster to do this in batches. I wanted to know the max node ID so that I know how many batches to do (the batches are defined by nodes whose ID is in a defined range), but I think it's easier to just keep looping until `MATCH (a:label) RETURN a LIMIT 1` returns null.

Comment: Label counts are extraordinarily fast, too, so you can always get your total by `MATCH (n:label) RETURN COUNT(*)`

Comment: Yes, I had noticed that was fast too. Is there one I should prefer, either in terms of performance or for more nebulous ideas of 'best practice'?

Comment: Label counts by far. That feature is basically never going to change, so they work very hard to support and optimize it, and will continue to do so regardless of what they do to underlying architecture. Plus it's easier to read the results from :)